# Polimorfismo en Java

Tags: java

¿Cuándo se usa polimorfismo se pueden sobrescribir los métodos y se sigue considerando polimorfismo?
por ejemplo: la clase padre hereda un método a la clase hija y en la clase hija sobre escribo ese método para agregarle un atributo propio de mi clase hija. ¿Se sigue considerando como polimorfismo?.

Comment: Claro que sí, mientras la firma del metodo sea la misma y esté presente en la jerarquía de clases

Comment: Muchas gracias.

Answer (score 2):

SI!, se sigue considerando polimorfismo, de hecho por eso es que se llama polimorfismo (por que adquiere diferentes formas)

Por ejemplo, si tienes una clase llamada Animal de la forma:

```
public class Animal{
    private int numeroPatas;
    private String nombre;

    public Animal(){
    }

    ....gettersAndSetters()....
}
```

Y luego creas la clase PerroHerido que hereda de animal:

```
public class PerroHerido extends Animal{
    private int numeroPatas;
    private int numeroPatasHeridas;
    private String raza;

    public PerroHerido(){
        super();
    }

    @Override
    public void setNumeroPatas(int ptasHeridas, int ptasBuenas){ //este método ya está en la clase padre pero lo sobreescribimos
        this.numeroPatas = ptasBuenas;
        this.numeroPatasHeridas = ptasHeridas;
    }
}
```

De esta manera la clase animal sigue siendo padre de la clase PerroHerido, pero la hija ha alterado uno de los métodos para definir otras propiedades o atributos de ella misma.

Aún así sigue siendo polimorfismo, cambió de forma en una de sus hijas.

Comment: Muchas gracias.

Answer (score 1):

Por supuesto que si, de hecho, de eso se trata el polimorfismo.

Un método heredado puede ser sobre-escrito para hacer su implementación más específica, y si tienes varias clases hijas por ejemplo Perro y Pez que heredan de Animal, puedes declarar un método abstracto en la clase padre llamado `moverse()` en el cual, tendrá un comportamiento distinto según la instancia a la que pertenezca el objeto.

Ejemplo:

```
Animal miPerro = new Perro();
Animal miPez = new Pez();

miPerro.moverse();
miPez.moverse();
```

Los métodos anteriores tendrán comportamientos distintos ya que son polimórficos.

Comment: Muchas gracias.